# How to divide the brain segmented slices in left and right compartments (halves)?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a series of `brain CT images`.
The goal is to segment brain followed by `separating brain into left and right halves` to compute brain area and blood area in each half.

I am attaching a zip file of 7 sample segmented brain images selected from a sequence (`not continuous slices just slices that may cover all types of slices`). [Link for sample images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPmQnkneBKo8RYDd3jarB2qefYv214-I/view?usp=sharing)

For this question, `I am trying to divide the brain into left and right compartments`.

I have been using to find left and right start indexes of the image to split into half. But this didn't give accurate results to divide into left and right halves.

My approach so far:

```
img_dir = pwd;
fileList = dir(img_dir);
fileList = fileList(~ismember({fileList.name},{'.','..'}));
num_of_slices = length(fileList);
for idx = 1: num_of_slices
    fileName = fileList(idx).name;
    img_slice_path = fullfile(img_dir,fileName);
    imgs{idx} = imread(img_slice_path);
    figure(1), imshow(imgs{idx},[]);
    pause(0.5);
end
%%
% seperate left and right based on midpoint of left_idx and right_idx
[nrow, ncol] = size(imgs{1});
[leftBrain_imgs,rightBrain_imgs] = deal(cell(1,length(imgs)));
for val = 1: length(imgs)
    tempImg = imgs{val};
      columnsWithAllZeros = all(tempImg == 0);
      left_idx = find(~columnsWithAllZeros,1,'first');
      right_idx = find(~columnsWithAllZeros,1,'last');
      cent_idx = floor(mean([left_idx,right_idx]));
      rightImg_idxs = 1:cent_idx; % right side is shown left
      leftImg_idxs = cent_idx+1:ncol; % left side is shown right
      [leftBrain_img,rightBrain_img]  = deal(zeros(nrow, ncol));
      rightBrain_img(:,rightImg_idxs) = tempImg(:,rightImg_idxs);
      leftBrain_img(:,leftImg_idxs) = tempImg(:,leftImg_idxs);
      leftBrain_imgs{val} = leftBrain_img;
      rightBrain_imgs{val} = rightBrain_img;
      figure(2),
      subplot(121), imshow(rightBrain_imgs{val},[]), title('right brain');
      subplot(122), imshow(leftBrain_imgs{val},[]), title('left brain');
      pause(0.5)
end
```

`Note: The brain may be slightly tilted slightly to the left or right`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks, Gopi

Comment: This is way too broad for SO. I've seen PhD theses written on this topic. It is not simple, and requires way more than can fit in an answer here.

Comment: any ideas would be great for me to explore and check if they fit for my requirement

Comment: For example [this PhD thesis from 2014 by R. Nordenskjöld at Uppsala University Dept. of Radiology](http://urn.kb.se/resolve?urn=urn:nbn:se:uu:diva-222376) proposes a method to segment the interhemispheric surface.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, I will check this.